# I want to write data from a service to a text field, but the error appears! UITextField.text should be used only from the main thread

Tags: swift

how to write in text field swift?

I want to write data from a service to a text field, but the error appears!

```
UITextField.text should be used only from the main thread
```

Help Please https://imgur.com/51CCXp5

```
if let jd = j as? [String: Any] {
    let dni = jd["dni"]
    let nombres = jd["name"]
    let apePat = jd["first_name"]
    let apeMat = jd["last_name"]
    print(dni as Any)
    print(nombres as Any)
    print(apePat as Any)
    print(apeMat as Any)
    
    txtNombres?.text = nombres as? String  **!UITextField.text must be used from main thread only**
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it inside

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.txtNombres?.text = nombres as? String
}
```